# Python 2.7 stdin not passing text to pipe

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

Okay guys, Python newbie here. What I'm looking to do is open a program (JLink Commander) and run a sequence of commands to automate programming of two microcontrollers on a PCB. So far I'm able to open the program, but I'm unable to pass my text via the pipe with stdin.

(Python 2.7, Windows 7.)

I can open the program with:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program File 
    (x86)\SEGGER\JLink_V632c\jlink.exe'])
```

but I try to make it a pipe, and this just makes the child seize up and close right away:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program File 
    (x86)\SEGGER\JLink_V632c\jlink.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Bigger code picture:

```
import os, subprocess, time

proc = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program File 
    (x86)\SEGGER\JLink_V632c\jlink.exe'])
time.sleep(1)
proc.stdin("power on")
proc.stdin.end()
```

(The delay is just to give JLink time to open, as that caused problems initially.)

I think I'm missing something totally basic here. I can do a workaround and use pyautogui -- it works, but it feels like using a rock because you don't know where you left your hammer.

Comment: Try swapping your backslashes with forward slashes. Python knows to turn forward slashes into back slashes and back slashes alone act as escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

According to: [[Python]: Popen.**communicate**(*input=None*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> ote that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`.

*code.py*:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import time


def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-c", "x = raw_input('Dummy prompt: ');print('\\nYou entered: {:s}'.format(x))"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    proc.communicate(input="Input text")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- As a workaround, I'm launching a new *python.exe* process, having as an argument a script that:

  - Waits for user input
  - Prints the (above) user input

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050935734>python code.py
> Python 2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Dummy prompt:
> You entered: Input text
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to avoid Popen.communicate because I want to leave the pipe to the child open.
Ideally, I'd have a line that would open the child and the pipes, and then I could send text commands using stdin or something similar.